# PHP errors in class-wp-query

Tags: php

New here but not sure how to figure out some PHP errors on my wordpress site.

I installed the Error Log Monitor plugin to monitor PHP errors as I am having an issue with another plugin (WP/LR sync) properly completing its task (it correctly uploads images from Lightroom to Wordpress but does not show as having uploaded those images as they remain in a 'to be published folder' in Lightroom). I find three errors repeating every 8 minutes in the log file:

Jun 03, 10:36:13
PHP Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /home/wednesda/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3736

Jun 03, 10:36:13
PHP Notice: Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /home/wednesda/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3738

Jun 03, 10:36:13
PHP Notice: Trying to get property 'post_name' of non-object in /home/wednesda/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3740

I looked at the class-wp-query file but cannot figure out the problem or where the error originates.

[image]

Would greatly appreciate your help.

Eyal